# DOM element manipulation in Angular is not working with (click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, dom

I am using Angular 2 in my application to render a data table (table-component). there is situation where we need to insert more rows in the table between existing rows on click of a button.
We have Created a separate component (alternates) that calls the rest service and create the template of rows to be inserted.

```
 <tbody [attr.id]="'alt_'+i" [style.display] = "displayRow != null && displayRow[i] && displayRow[i] === true ? '' : 'none'">
            <alternates (success)="changeRowColor($event)"></alternates>
        </tbody>
```

We are calling this component from table-component and able to load the Component on runtime, but the problem is all the table rows gets fit into single column (don't know why)

The weird thing is if we change something in dom it looks fine, so to fix this problem we manipulates the dom and replace the HTML with same html,

```
 $("#rowid").html($("#rowid").html());
```

this way we fix the UI problem but after doing that we are not able to call any click event present in the alternates component.

Can you please give me any suggestion?  How can I fix this problem.

Comment: The fact is you should not manipulate the dom while using angular 2, that's renderer's job.

Comment: Then there is another way to do it ?

Comment: @user3614970 use a custom directive

Comment: Please provide more information (code) about what you want to manipulate in what way and from where.

Comment: open chrome dev console and see if the dom is correct for table. table has strict requirements in term of tbody>td>td and nothing in between.